# No WiFi device available

Tags: iwlwifi

Since a couple of days, my WiFi card keeps disappearing from Ubuntu once in a while for a couple of restarts. I have attached my system log, does anyone have an idea what the issue could be? Usually, it first says 'device not ready', and after a restart 'no networking devices available'. I have used Ubuntu on this Dell XPS 13 machine for a year now, never had similar issues. Also, a fresh install didn't change anything. Even the live system might not detect the device.

[System logfile after disappear and reappear](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu42ttjqday8odg/log)

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I tried installing the newest driver from the intel site. 
All you need to know is the name of your device and your kernel version. Use `uname --all` and `lspci` and download the driver [here](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm), than copy it to your `/lib/firmware`-folder.
That worked for me.